# Adding a column and new foreign key constraint in one line

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, alter-table

Let's say we have a table called Salesman with the folling properties

```
Create Table SalesMan(
  EmplyeeId int Primary Key,
  Name varchar(20) Not Null,
  LastName Varchar(20) Not Null,
  Email Varchar(40) Unique);
```

and a simple table definition for "Order"

```
Create Table Orders(
  Number Varchar(20),
  Quantity Int,
  DealerCode Varchar(20),
  ModelName Varchar(20),
  ModelVersion Varchar(20));
```

At this point I forgot to add a One to Many relation between Order and Salesman so that a SalesMan can have many orders and Orders can have only one Salesman

```
Alter Table Orders Add sm_fk int;
Alter Table Orders Add Constraint Sales_fk Foreign Key (sm_fk) References SalesMan(EmplyeeId)
```

Now my question is: could I have simplified the query by omitting the second alter table query and compress it to

```
Alter Table Orders add sm_fk int References SalesMan(EmplyeeId)
```

Would this be the same as the second Alter Table query?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, they're the same.  You can specify a foreign key constraint during column creation, or afterwards in an alter command.  Only difference is that you've explicitly specified the name "Sales_fk" in the two-queries version.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` allows to specify more than one action, so both queries may be combined into one - in such case both constraint symbol and index name may be specified.